# gsutil parallel composite speed decreases over time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am trying to upload a 1GB file via gsutil. Here is the command I'm using:

```
$ gsutil -o GSUtil:parallel_composite_upload_threshold=150M 
  cp /Users/david/Desktop/pricing20160112/c_price  
  gs://docs_test

Copying file:///Users/david/Desktop/pricing20160112/c_price
```

The first 80% of the upload works just fine and fast, but then the speed decreases from about 40 MB/s to less than 1 MB/s. Comparing this against Google Drive, the upload speed is always consistent, and it doesn't 'slow down' towards the end -- so this seems to be an issue with `gsutil` (or something else), but not with network bandwidth.

Here's a video showing how the upload slows down to near a halt towards the end: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4-aY1CPM-M (view it in 1080p full-screen to see the details). What is going on here, and why does it start slowing down? Is there a way to prevent this? Note that this is being tested on a mac.